# Opening image in Illustrator in its original size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

When using the File>Open command to open an image, the image appears to be resized smaller. How do I open the image in its original size? Also, I'm not talking about File>Place.

Comment: The zoom is set to 37.4%.  Try setting it at 100%.  Does that help?

Comment: @BillyKerr No, the image itself was opened at 205x288 px when its supposed to be 1000x1401. Though, the canvas itself is 1000x1401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document needs to have the same PPI settings as the image being loaded in.

You can load the image into Photoshop and then change the PPI and then load it into Illustrator.

---

I used to have this problem a lot, I've decided on 72 ppi for editing in Illustrator as it is less strenuous on my system and I usually design things that won't be printed anyhow.

Comment: How do I change the PPI settings? I'm also using 72 PPI for this.

Comment: Illustrator does not really have PPI it is just for pixel effectsm which odds are you are never using

Comment: Seems that it works fine if the image is in png. Thanks for the tips!